# Coin Change Problem Top-Down Approach: Failing for below case with denominations: [357,239,73,52] and total 9832

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

```
public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
        return coinChange(coins, amount, 0, new Integer[amount+1]);
    }
    
    private int coinChange(int[] coins, int remaining, int start, Integer[] memo){
        if(remaining == 0){
            return 0; 
        }
        
        if(remaining<0){
            return -1;
        }
        
        if(memo[remaining]!=null){
            return memo[remaining];
        }
        
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        
//but if I am running loop from i=0 it passes , I think it should work from start as well, as it already discover the optimal min in previous steps for example for [5,1,3,2] coins denominations ,if I have to make 11 than going from 5 exploring 3,  is same as going from 3 exploring 5, that's why I am staring from start.
for(int i=start; i<coins.length; i++){
            int res = coinChange(coins, remaining-coins[i], i, memo);
            if(res>=0){
                min = Math.min(min, res+1);
            }   
        }
        min = ((min == Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? -1:min);
        return memo[remaining] = min;
    }
```

Comment: What are the coins denomination?

Comment: You don't need the loop. There are two cases. Use the current coin, in which case the recursive call is `remaining - coins[start], start`.  Don't use the current coin, in which case the recursive call is `remaining, start + 1`. Of course, that means that the `memo` table must be a 2D table indexed by `remaining` and `start`. The issue is that if `remaining` is a large number, and the only coin is small, the recursion stack could overflow. So what you could do is create a loop for the quantity of the current coin.

Comment: The solution with the lowest number of coins is `20 * 357 + 10 * 239 + 3 * 73 + 2 * 52 == 9832`.